# How to calculate time required by PHP file to open using wget?

Tags: php, perl, wget

I want to find out the time required by a php file to open(download) inside a Perl script. I want to use wget here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) to calculate the time:

```
/**
 * Simple function to replicate PHP 5 behaviour
 */
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

$time_start = microtime_float();

// do stuff

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Execution time was $time seconds\n";
```